# add_subplot() not working if fig = plt.figure() is in another cell in Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I ran into a weird problem using matplotlib in Ipython Notebook. Here is the code:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(np.random.randn(10), 'k--')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(np.random.randn(10), 'r--')
```

This works fine and generates an inline figure with two subplots. However, if I put the same code into two cells like this:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

```py
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(np.random.randn(10), 'k--')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(np.random.randn(10), 'r--')
```

Then there is no inline images generated at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `inline` backend closes a figure after a cell has been fully executed.

You're best approach is to merge those cells.